# how to read one line to calculate the md5

Tags: bash, shell, md5sum

I am using Linux bash version 4.1.2

I have a tab-delimited input_file having 5 fields and I want to calculate the MD5 for each line and put the md5sum at the end of each line.

The expected output_file should therefore has 6 fields for each line.

Here is my coding:

```
cat input_file | while read ONELINE
do
  THEMD5=`echo "$ONELINE" | md5sum | awk '{print $1}'`
  echo -e "${ONELINE}\t${THEMD5}"
done > output_file
```

The coding works well most of the time.

However, if ONELINE is ended with single/double tabs, the trailing tab(s) will disappear!

As a result, the output_file will sometimes contain lines of 4 or 5 fields, due to the missing tab(s).

I have tried to add `IFS=` or `IFS=''` or `IFS=$'\n'` or `IFS-$'\012'` in the `while` statement, but still cannot solve the problem.

Please help.

Alvin SIU

Comment: If you have issues this doesn't address, you'll need to provide a SSCCE that demonstrates it -- in this case, amending your script to generate its own input would suffice. For instance: `< <(printf 'hello\nhello\t\t\n')` -- if those two lines had different md5sums, it would clearly demonstrate the bug.

Comment: See http://ideone.com/UqYj7R for an example of a **complete** MCVE, including (working!) input data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is quite certainly correct, if you want trailing newlines included in your md5sums (as your original code has):

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  read sum _ < <(printf '%s\n' "$line" | md5sum -)
  printf '%s\t%s\n' "$line" "$sum"
done <input_file
```

Notes:

- Characters inside IFS are stripped by `read`; setting `IFS=` is sufficient to prevent this effect.
- Without the `-r` argument, `read` also interprets backslash literals, stripping them.
- Using `echo -e` is dangerous: It interprets escape sequences inside your line, rather than emitting them as literals.
- Using all-uppercase variable names is bad form. See [the relevant spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html) (particularly the fourth paragraph), keeping in mind that shell variables and environment variables share a namespace.
- Using `echo` in general is bad form when dealing with uncontrolled data (particularly including data which can contain backslash literals). See [the relevant POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html), particularly the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections.
- If you want to print the lines in a way that makes hidden characters visible, consider using `'%q\t%s\n'` instead of `'%s\t%s\n'` as a format string.

Comment: Thanks Charles! The code works.  My bash cannot use the [[[ read sum ]]] statement.  I have to use the statement [[[ read sum _ <<< $( xxx ) ]]]

Comment: @AlvinSIU, precisely which version of bash are you running? Everything here is supported back through the 3.x series.

Comment: @AlvinSIU, ...as such, as long as your shell _really is_ bash (as opposed to `/bin/sh`), I'd expect typos or transcription errors to be more likely than genuine incompatibility. Did you copy-and-paste?

Comment: @AlvinSIU, ...if you _did_ copy-and-paste and got an error, check that you're using `#!/bin/bash` rather than `#!/bin/sh`, or `bash scriptname` rather than `sh scriptname`.

Comment: @AlvinSIU, ...assuming, that is, that you're on a real UNIX platform and not using Git Bash -- if it's the latter, I'd suggest upgrading one of the current releases (from https://msysgit.github.io/), which are no longer based on the ancient, buggy mingw build.

Comment: @AlvinSIU, ...part of why I so strongly suggest avoiding `read <<<"$( ... )"`, by the way, is that command substitution has side effects -- in particular, it trims trailing newlines. If your goal is byte-for-byte accuracy, it's a bad place to be.

Comment: Thanks Charles for your comments.  I just got back from lunch.  I found out why my script cannot  use the `read sum _ < <( xxx )`.  Actually, I have to use the coding in a large script.  Inside that large script, there is a `set -o posix` at the beginning.  I have tried to remove this `set` statement in the UAT enviroment and find out your code works.  BTW, actually, I do not need the newline for md5sum.

Comment: If you want the checksum to not include the trailing newline, change `printf '%s\n' "$line"` to `printf '%s' "$line"` in the code above, and it'll exclude them.