# Linux piping find and md5sum not sending output

Tags: linux, pipe, md5sum

Trying to loop every file, do some cutting, extract the first 4 characters of the MD5.

Here's what I got so far:

```
find . -name *.jpg | cut -f4 -d/ | cut -f1 -d. | md5sum | head -c 4
```

Problem is, I don't see any more output at this point. How can I send output to `md5sum` and continue sending the result?

Comment: Are you trying to compute the md5sums of the files?  That's not happening here.

Comment: no, i want to compute md5 of the text output from the pipe

Comment: Is the `find` command finishing?

Comment: the `find` command will take hours to complete. do i have to wait for it to finish? i want to get md5 line by line and perform additional operations

Comment: The command you wrote computes a single MD5 hash of the whole `find`/`cut` result.

Comment: i need md5 of just the file name one at a time not whole stream. looks like ill have to python this one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

md5sum reads everything from stdin till end of file (eof) and outputs md5 sum of full file. You should separate input into lines and run md5sum per line, for example with `while read var` loop:

```
find . -name *.jpg | cut -f4 -d/ | cut -f1 -d. | 
  while read -r a; 
   do   echo -n $a| md5sum | head -c 4; 
  done
```

[`read` builtin bash command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-read) will read  one line from input into shell variable `$a`; `while` loop will run loop body (commands between `do` and `done`) for every return from read, and $a will be the current line. -r option of read is to not convert backslash; -n option of echo command will not add newline (if you want newline, remove -n option of echo).

This will be slow for thousands of files and more, as there are several forks/execs for every file inside loop. Faster will be some scripting with perl or python or nodejs or any other scripting language with builtin md5 hash computing (or with some library).

Comment: Same loop was used in https://stackoverflow.com/a/5890196, similar in https://stackoverflow.com/a/31955350

Comment: this is what i was looking to do but couldnt figure out how

Answer (score 1):

How to find all .jpg file then execute md5sum then cut first 4 caracters:

```
find . -name '*.jpg'  -exec md5sum {} \; | cut -b 1-4
```

Comment: i need md5 of the file name (no extension), not the whole path to file

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you are attempting to do with a short "*helper*" script that you call from `find`. For example, you could create a short script to find the `basename` of each file passed as an argument, remove the `'.jpg'` extension, and then provide the remaining name w/o extension as input to `md5sum` on `stdin` to get the `md5sum` of the name itself. Call the script anything you like, say `namemd5.sh`. Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

[ -z "$1" ] && exit 1           ## validate single argument

fname=$(basename "$1")          ## get the filename alone
fname="${fname%.jpg}"           ## remove .jpg extension

fnsum=$(md5sum - <<<"$fname")   ## get md5sum of name w/o .jpg
fnsum=${fnsum%% *}              ## remove trailing ' -'

echo "$fnsum - $fname"          ## output md5sum - name
                                ## (remove ' - $fname' for md5sum alone)
```

(**note:** the name is provided as part of the output for example purposes, remove if you want the `md5sum` alone as shown in the comment above)

**Example Files**

```
$ find /home/david/img/wp/ -type f -name "*.jpg"
/home/david/img/wp/hacker_manifesto_1200x900.jpg
/home/david/img/wp/hacker_manifesto_by_otalicus.jpg
/home/david/img/wp/reflections-triple-1920x1200.jpg
/home/david/img/wp/hacker_wallpaper_1600x900.jpg
/home/david/img/wp/Zen.jpg
/home/david/img/wp/hacker_wallpaper_by_vanilla23-dot254.jpg
/home/david/img/wp/hacker_manifesto_1600x900.jpg
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ find /home/david/img/wp/ -type f -name "*.jpg" -exec ./namemd5.sh '{}' \;
0f7d2aac158eb9f7842215e14ff6573c - hacker_manifesto_1200x900
604bc695a0bb70b8db0352267caf226f - hacker_manifesto_by_otalicus
5decea0e306f185bf988ac9934ec0e2c - reflections-triple-1920x1200
82bd8e1ad3df588eb0e0848c5f764812 - hacker_wallpaper_1600x900
0f4daba431a22c03f28977f087e4c695 - Zen
0c55cd3ebd2a847e10c20d86e80e6ceb - hacker_wallpaper_by_vanilla23-dot254
e5c1da0c2db3827d2bf81c306633cc56 - hacker_manifesto_1600x900
```

You can also call the script with the `-execdir` version within `find` as well, e.g.

```
$ find /home/david/img/wp/ -type f -name "*.jpg" -execdir \
/full/path/to/namemd5.sh '{}' \;
```

(**note:** the use of the `/full/path` to your helper script above)